# Calling an outside function via inline jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call an outside function from `USER-APP.JS` from my inline code, and I continue to receive `user is not defined.`

When I run the code from `USER-APP.JS` inline it works fine. Myself and my coleague cannot find a bug, so we are seeking help from the internet.

Yes, the `USER-APP.JS` is being loaded before the inline code is run.

// INLINE

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        user.timer_start();
        alert('ready');
    });
</script>
```

// USER-APP.JS

```
user = {
    timer_start: function() {
        alert('test');

        austDay = 3700;
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    }
};
```

Comment: did you include `USER-APP.JS` before calling the function?

Comment: Yes @Viscocent I think I may have figured it out I had something on my computer using the same port via localhost and it was screwing with the way it was executing.